# php constructed objects classes location? any storage location?

Tags: php, object

Where does the initialized class objects reside in storage ?
How to see consumption of storage or cache by these objects in a running server for a specific web application?

I'm asking so I could check how many objects got initialized or ended or resided after the execution of application.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php May this link will help you

Comment: "After execution" nothing remains. The entire PHP environment is torn down, including everything in memory, including every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm asking so I could check how many objects got initialized or ended
>   or resided after the execution of application.

Simple answer is "nothing". Once the execution is complete all memory used for instantiatedated objects, variables etc is released.
Nothing is written to persistent storage unless you manually do it by for instance [serializing](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) an object and writing it to a file.